# "What an X?" or just "What X?"

Tags: articles

We sometimes say, **"What a catch!"** (in Spanish, "Qué atrapada!) or, **"What a wonderful world!"** (in Spanish, "¡Qué mundo maravilloso!")

Why do we use "a" in those phrases? After all, when we translate "¡Qué elegancia!" that just becomes "What elegance!"

So, my question is: When should I include the "a", and when should I leave it out?

Answer (score 1):

Note that we use pretty much the same pattern in ordinary declaratives:

> That was **a** fine catch, *and*
>   It's **a** wonderful world, *but*
>   She has such **∅** elegance.

*Catch* and *world* designate entities—an action and a physical object—but *elegance* designates an abstract quality (really just a nominal derivative of an adjective) which may be ascribed to an entity.

By the same token, we do not speak of **an** *elegance* or of *elegances*, except to mark the fact that we are speaking of one or more distinct instances of *elegance*.

Answer (score 1):

A simple grammar rule:

We say:

What **wonderful coffee**!
What **tasty lemonade**!

1. Those are **mass nouns**.

What **a wonderful world**!
What **great song**!

2. ***World* is not a mass noun.** It is a countable noun.

And finally, in Spanish, words about states or conditions, **do not take a determiner.**

"Such elegance!" OR "What elegance!"
"¡Qué elegancia!"

Nor do single nouns take determiners in Spanish here:

""¡Qué buena comida!"